# c-mpi（BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES EXIT CODE: 139）

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mpi

I am encountering a segmentation fault in my application, with the specific error message being: “YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)”. This issue indicates that my program is facing a severe memory access problem during execution.

I have tried some basic debugging steps but have yet to identify the root cause of the problem. I would like to share the debugging strategies I have considered so far and seek advice and assistance from the community.

The debugging strategies I have attempted include:

1. Checking for memory access violations, such as array out-of-bounds access, dereferencing null pointers, or using freed memory.
2. Considering the use of debugging tools like GDB to pinpoint the exact location of the issue.
3. Reviewing memory management for proper allocation and deallocation of dynamically allocated memory.
4. Checking for stack overflow issues, such as recursive functions without a proper base case.
5. Investigating potential data corruption issues, like buffer overflow.
6. Reviewing third-party libraries I am using to see if they might be the source of the issue.
7. Revisiting recent changes made to the code to identify any potential problems introduced.
   Here is some specific context about my problem:

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>

const int M = 6000;
const int N = 8000;
const double epsilon = 0.01;

double odt[M][N];
double t[M][N];

void init_data(double t[M][N], int start_row, int end_row, int world_rank, int world_size) {
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            t[0][j] = 0.0;
        }
    }
    if (world_rank == world_size - 1) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            t[M - 1][j] = 100.0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = start_row; i < end_row; i++) {
        t[i][0] = 100.0;
        t[i][N - 1] = 100.0;
    }
}


void init_mean(double t[M][N], double& mean, int start_row, int end_row, int world_rank, int world_size) {
    double local_mean = 0.0;
    int local_count = 0;

    for (int i = start_row; i < end_row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            local_mean += t[i][j];
            local_count++;
        }
    }

    double global_sum;
    int global_count;
    MPI_Allreduce(&local_mean, &global_sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Allreduce(&local_count, &global_count, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    mean = world_rank == 0 ? global_sum / global_count : 0.0;
}


void init_interior(double(&t)[M][N], double mean, int start_row, int end_row, int world_rank, int world_size) {
    int update_start = start_row;
    int update_end = world_rank == world_size - 1 ? end_row - 1 : end_row;

    for (int i = update_start; i < update_end; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < N - 1; j++) {
            t[i][j] = mean;
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // param
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int world_size, world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    int local_M = M / world_size;
    int start_row = world_rank * local_M;
    int end_row = start_row + local_M;
    if (world_rank == world_size - 1) {
        end_row = M;  
    }
    int update_start;
    int update_end;

    double mean = 0.0;
    int iterations = 0;
    int iterations_print = 1;
    double diff = epsilon;
    //clock_t time0, time1;
    //double duration;

    // init    
    init_data(t, start_row, end_row, world_rank, world_size);
    init_mean(t, mean, start_row, end_row, world_rank, world_size);
    init_interior(t, mean, start_row, end_row, world_rank, world_size);

    // solve    
    double start_time, end_time;
    start_time = MPI_Wtime(); 

    while (epsilon <= diff) {

        for (int i = start_row; i < end_row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                odt[i][j] = t[i][j];
            }
        }
  
        MPI_Request send_request[2], recv_request[2];
        MPI_Status status[2];


        if (world_rank > 0) {
            MPI_Sendrecv(&t[start_row][0], N, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank - 1, 0,
                &t[start_row - 1][0], N, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank - 1, 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }


        if (world_rank < world_size - 1) {
            MPI_Sendrecv(&t[end_row - 1][0], N, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank + 1, 0,
                &t[end_row][0], N, MPI_DOUBLE, world_rank + 1, 0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        }

        
        update_start = world_rank == 0 ? start_row : start_row + 1;
        update_end = world_rank == world_size - 1 ? end_row : end_row - 1;

        for (int i = update_start; i < update_end; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < N - 1; j++) {
                t[i][j] = (odt[i - 1][j] + odt[i + 1][j] + odt[i][j - 1] + odt[i][j + 1]) / 4.0;
            }
        }

        

        double my_diff = 0.0;
        //diff = 0.0;
        /*update_start = world_rank == 0 ? start_row : start_row + 1;
        update_end = world_rank == world_size - 1 ? end_row : end_row - 1;*/
        for (int i = update_start; i < update_end; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < N - 1; j++) {
                my_diff = fmax(my_diff, fabs(t[i][j] - odt[i][j]));
            }
        }
        // Synchronize diff
        MPI_Allreduce(&my_diff, &diff, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

       /* if (diff < my_diff) {
            diff = my_diff;
        }*/

        
            if (world_rank == 0 && iterations == iterations_print) {
                printf("  %8d  %f\n", iterations, diff);
                iterations_print *= 2;
            }
        iterations++;
      
    }
    end_time = MPI_Wtime(); 
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        printf("\n");
        printf("  %8d  %f\n", iterations, diff);
        printf("\n");
        printf("  Error tolerance achieved.\n");
        printf("Wallclock time = %f\n", end_time - start_time);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I just want someone can help finding out where the problem is

Comment: Are you using a reference in C as the second parameter of the init_mean function?

Comment: `double& mean` isn't C code. Are you using the right compiler?

Comment: Run in a debugger or at least with valgrind.